# how to convert String to Date in android

Tags: java, android, date

I have string date time "2014-10-13 18:22:54.71", I want to convert that to `Date` and

I'll use that algorithm

```
public static boolean IsthatMorethanTwo(String DateString) {
    Calendar thatDay = Calendar.getInstance();
    thatDay.setTime(new Date(DateString));
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    long diff = today.getTimeInMillis() - thatDay.getTimeInMillis();
    long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    return days >= 2;
}
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class.

Like this:

```
String dateString = "2014-10-13 18:22:54.71";    
SimpleDateFormat format = 
        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.S");

try {
    Date parsed = format.parse(dateString);
}
catch(ParseException pe) {
    System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot parse \"" + dateString + "\"");
}
```